# Trying to recreate this vertical nav bar using CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to  reproduce the uneven width vertical nav bar used in the following site:

http://www.narrowdesign.com/

The vertical sliding effect and the pulsing bars are totally optional, not something I must have. I do like the effect of the bars widening when you mouse over.

Any suggestions on how to do this with CSS and or jquery?

Comment: I think you will need javascript/jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward. Just use a bunch of `<ul>` elements with black backgrounds and some padding. You can put `float:left;` and `clear:both;` on them and they will line up down the side and be sized to fit their content.

Comment: You'll have to turn ON javascript! ;)